# When reading a Json object array and creating the csv file the first column is emply from the second record and foward

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, csv

I have this JSON Object array (excerpt).  In my Javascript I am creating a csv with the values I wanted with an iteration function.  The problem is that the first record of the csv is created correctly but from the second record and forward is creating an empty first column. It has a comma as the first character and I don't know what in my logic is causing it.  Can you help?  See the code below:

```
"recs-count": 139, 
"gps-recs": [
    { 
        "RecId": 40020551513, 
        "City": "New Port Richey", 
        "Country": "USA", 
        "County": "PASCO", 
        "State": "FL", 
        "Street": "1546 Amaryllis ct.", 
        "ZipCode": "34655", 
        "CurrentOdometer": 12161, 
        "Heading": 0, 
        "Latitude": 28.181690, 
        "Longitude": -82.658420, 
        "SpeedMph": 0, 
        "SpeedLimitMph": 25, 
        "Status": "Stopped", 
        "StatusDuration": "1.05:00:00", 
        "PrimaryLandmarkName": "Max's home", 
        "CurrentHardmountEvent": null, 
        "UtcTimeTag": "2013-11-28T05:23:34", 
        "UserTimeTag": "2013-11-28T00:23:34", 
        "UserInfo": { 
            "UserId": 201274, 
            "UserNumber": "22", 
            "UserName": "Max's Car" 
        } 
    },
    { 
        "RecId": 40020551610, 
        "City": "New Port Richey", 
        "Country": "USA", 
        "County": "PASCO", 
        "State": "FL", 
        "Street": "1546 Amaryllis ct.", 
        "ZipCode": "34655", 
        "CurrentOdometer": 12161, 
        "Heading": 0, 
        "Latitude": 28.181690, 
        "Longitude": -82.658410,
```

Code:

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  var result = JSON.parse(body)['gps-recs'];
    console.log(result);
    console.log(Object.keys(result).length);
  //console.log(body);
  buildCSV(result); 

});
function buildCSV(result) {
    // loop runs result.length times
    for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(result).length; i++) {

            csvFile.push(result[i].UserInfo.UserNumber + ',' + result[i].UtcTimeTag + ',' + result[i].Latitude + ',' + result[i].Longitude + ',' + result[i].Speed + ',' + result[i].Heading + '\r\n' );
            console.log(csvFile[i]);
        };

    fs.writeFile('file.csv', csvFile, function(err) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log('file saved');
    });
};
```

This is the file created (txt viewed):

```
2169266287,2015-10-27T04:00:05,25.796945,-80.255766,undefined,100,
,2164309328,2015-10-27T04:00:20,42.224414,-83.347603,undefined,0,
,2162029911,2015-10-27T04:00:46,41.500245,-81.681383,undefined,0,
,2164328304,2015-10-27T04:01:19,42.238847,-83.32803,undefined,0,
,2164309328,2015-10-27T04:01:28,42.22442,-83.347484,undefined,0,
,2162029911,2015-10-27T04:01:46,41.500245,-81.681383,undefined,0,
,2164328304,2015-10-27T04:02:23,42.23782,-83.328911,undefined,0,
,2164309328,2015-10-27T04:02:39,42.224411,-83.34745,undefined,0,
,2162029911,2015-10-27T04:02:46,41.50021,-81.681347,undefined,140,
,2164328304,2015-10-27T04:03:12,42.238956,-83.325409,undefined,0,
,2169655749,2015-10-27T04:03:24,25.797042,-80.260972,undefined,136,
,2162029911,2015-10-27T04:03:46,41.50021,-81.681347,undefined,0,
,2164309328,2015-10-27T04:03:49,42.224419,-83.347445,undefined,0,
,2162029911,2015-10-27T04:04:46,41.50021,-81.681347,undefined,0,
,2164309328,2015-10-27T04:05:05,42.22442,-83.347456,undefined,0,
,2164328304,2015-10-27T04:05:29,42.238716,-83.327105,undefined,211,
,2162029911,2015-10-27T04:05:46,41.50021,-81.681347,undefined,0,
,2164309328,2015-10-27T04:06:28,42.22441,-83.347477,undefined,0,
,2164328304,2015-10-27T04:06:32,42.239021,-83.32724,undefined,256,
```

This is how the JSON Object looks like after parsing:
[image]

**The working code is as follows:**
I had to change the array with the CSV format data into a string (variable).  The fs.write module needed a string, not an array.  That's why the data was changed after going through fs write module.  Thank you all for your help!

```
var request = require("request");
var fs = require ('fs');
var csvFile = "";
var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'URL',
   };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  var result = JSON.parse(body)['gps-recs'];

    console.log(Object.keys(result).length);
    console.log(result.length);

  buildCSV(result); 

});
function buildCSV(result) {
    // loop runs result.length times

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

    csvFile = csvFile.concat(result[i].UserInfo.UserNumber + ',' + result[i].UtcTimeTag + ',' + result[i].Latitude + ',' + result[i].Longitude + ',' + result[i].Speed + ',' + result[i].Heading + '\r\n');

        };
    console.log(csvFile);
    fs.writeFile('file.csv', csvFile, function(err) {
      //fs.writeFile('file.csv', csvFile, function(err) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log('file saved');
    });
};
```

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: it is below the json object excerpt  :) sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are building an array called cvsFile where each element in the array represents a line in the file. You are then passing the array to the writeFile method. The writeFile method is expecting a string or Buffer. The writeFile method is converting the array to a string by joining the elements using "," as a separator. I believe you need to create the string yourself by joining the elements using the empty string "" as a separator. Then you can pass that string to the writeFile method. For example...

```
fs.writeFile('file.csv', csvFile.join(""), function(err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log('file saved');
});
```

Comment: Ah that would make sense. I was wondering why there was a uneexplained comma both at the end of the line and the beginning of the next line. A string concat with "," would output the value: ,\r\n,

Comment: @DerekVanCuyk -  changing to a string variable and the ,concat the elements with "," and \r\n at the end of each line made it work. Then, I didn't have to specify the csvFile.join when calling the writeFile method. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that the buildCSV method is iterating through the members defined on the object and not the number of records in the collection.

You want to define your method as such:

```
function buildCSV(result) {
    // loop runs result.length times
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { // **this was changed**

            csvFile.push(result[i].UserInfo.UserNumber + ',' + result[i].UtcTimeTag + ',' + result[i].Latitude + ',' + result[i].Longitude + ',' + result[i].Speed + ',' + result[i].Heading + '\r\n' );
            console.log(csvFile[i]);
        };

    fs.writeFile('file.csv', csvFile, function(err) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log('file saved');
    });
};
```

The [Object.Keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fkeys) property which you're using essentially enumerates through all of the properties defined on an object whereas it looks like you want to cycle through the array instead.

Comment: I tried this and with the same result.  I think is has to do with something between arrays in the JSON file. Maybe when reading the extra " }," that only occurs from the 2nd instance and forward.. I don't know.  thank you anyway :)

Comment: What does the data look like in the console when you do this: var result = JSON.parse(body)['gps-recs'];
    console.log(result);

Comment: I added the screen shot after the csv file in my question, thank you.